# PHP Hash Key Array

Tags: php, arrays, hash

I came across this simple PHP Class on GitHub while searching for Bloom Filters, this was named as a "Bloom Filter" but I think it is more of a "Hash Table" either way I am curious, it is very simple to understand.

It reads in a file of words and creates a Hash Array Key for each word, you can then check if the word exist in the Hash Array.

I am curious though is there any benefit of using this versus just storing the actual word as the array key or value and then checking if that word exist in the array, in theory this would just be adding overhead and doing the same thing, please help me understand what I am missing?

```
<?php
class Dictionary {
    private $words;
    private $wordsHash;
    public $hashLength;

    public function __construct($filepath, $hashLength) {
        $this->words = file($filepath);
        $this->hashLength = $hashLength;
        foreach($this->words as $word){
            $this->wordsHash[$this->createHash($word)] = true;
        }
        echo 'words: ' . count($this->words) . '   hashes: ' . count($this->wordsHash) . "\n";
    }

    public function createHash($str){
        $hash = substr(md5(trim($str)), 0, $this->hashLength);
        return $hash;
    }

    public function checkDictionary($str){
        $hash = $this->createHash(trim($str));
        if(array_key_exists ($hash , $this->wordsHash)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

dictionary.txt file has 10,000 words in it, I will just show a few for demo

```
der
die
und
in
den
von
zu
das
mit
sich
des
auf
für
ist
```

Example usage:

```
<?php
$dictionary = new Dictionary('dictionary.txt', 30);

if($dictionary->checkDictionary('den')){
    echo 'The Word den Exist in the Hash Table';
}else{
    echo 'The Word den DOES NOT Exist in the Hash Table';
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems to me that you could just do this with normal php arrays which act like hashes

Comment: @hackartist: Thats what I was thinking but I figured there must be a reason someone went through the trouble of making this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea with this seems to be that searching for a key is much faster than searching for a specific value in an array. This is especially true for very large arrays. However, I would recommend a simpler approach to (as you already said) avoid overhead and collisions:

```
$words = array_flip( file($filename) );

// The actual values are now the keys!
// So checking for a word works like this:
if (isset($words['und'])) {
    // ...

// Travling through the words works like this:
foreach ($words as $word => $i) {
    // ...
```

(PS: This code will not work as expected since every word will include the line break, so you will need to strip that first. But I hope you get the idea.)

Answer (score 3):

This sort of approach is generally done with very large strings. I've once used this method when creating a gallery. The uploaded file will be named after the `sha1` checksum of the entire file (while the actual name is saved in a database). This way, if a duplicate file is uploaded, it would be denied easily.

I don't know exactly what benefit would he gain from hashing 3 letter strings (or even 50 letter strings for that matter). I wouldn't do it that way. You'll have the ask the original developer.

Answer (score 2):

If you found it on github - it's probably worth asking the author of the code you've found.

The dictionary class does have 2 benefits - it trims keys, and avoid duplicates but the following code is mostly equivalent, and likely to be a lot faster:

```
$words = file($filepath);
$words = array_map('trim', $words);
$words = array_unique($words);
sort($words); // just for convenience debugging

...

if (in_array($test, $words)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

If in doubt, benchmarking each (or any) competing technique should clearly indicate which is the best solution for a given use case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference that I see between that constructor and just using the words themselves as the keys. Arrays in php with non-numeric are essentially hashmaps (in syntax and in implementation, if I recall correctly). Consider this snippet:

```
$contents = file($filepath);
$dictionary = array();
foreach($contents as $word) {
    $dictionary[$word] = $word;
}

if(array_key_exists('den', $dictionary){
    echo 'The Word den Exist in the Hash Table';
}else{
    echo 'The Word den DOES NOT Exist in the Hash Table';
}
```

It does the same thing as the sample class. The only thing you lose is the `->` syntax, but you could technically use `$dictionary['den']` as your exists condition... It returns null if it isn't set, which evaluates to false, so...

The class also commits a computer science no-no of using a cyptographic hash function where cryptograpic security is not required. The MD5 algorithm is a lot more expensive to run than a regular, non-secure (relatively; calling MD5 secure is dubious by this point) hash function. Using the dictionary class would be significantly slower in addition to not really providing anything. As Truth points out, comparing digests of very long strings can save you time. But computing the digests is still expensive and computing digests for 3 letter strings is nothing but a waste of time.